# spark convert multiple rows into single row with multiple collections

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking for ideas on how to solve below scenario. my use case is in java spark, but looking for ideas on how to do it irrespective of language as I ran out of ideas

I have unstructured data as below

```
98480|PERSON|TOM|GREER|1982|12|27
98480|PHONE|CELL|732|201|6789
98480|PHONE|HOME|732|123|9876
98480|ADDR|RES|102|JFK BLVD|PISCATAWAY|NJ|08854
98480|ADDR|OFF|211|EXCHANGE PL|JERSEY CITY|NJ|07302
98481|PERSON|LIN|JASSOY|1976|09|15
98481|PHONE|CELL|908|398|3389
98481|PHONE|HOME|917|363|2647
98481|ADDR|RES|111|JOURNAL SQ|JERSEY CITY|NJ|07704
98481|ADDR|OFF|365|DOWNTOWN NEWYORK|NEWYORK CITY|NY|10001
```

I am trying to convert them into row with persondata with set of phone and addr something like below, basically single row for each personId

```
+--------+------+---------+--------+----+-----+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|personId|type  |firstName|lastName|year|month|day|Phone                                                                | addr                                                                                                                 |                                                                                                                                                               |
+--------+------+---------+--------+----+-----+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|98481   |PERSON|LIN      |JASSOY  |1976|09   |15 |[[PHONE, HOME, 917, 363, 2647], [PHONE, CELL, 908, 398, 3389]]       | [[ADDR, OFF, 365, DOWNTOWN NEWYORK, NEWYORK CITY, NY, 10001], [ADDR, RES, 111, JOURNAL SQ, JERSEY CITY, NJ, 07704]]  |
|98480   |PERSON|TOM      |GREER   |1982|12   |27 |[[PHONE, HOME, 732, 123, 9876], [PHONE, CELL, 732, 201, 6789]]       | [[ADDR, RES, 102, JFK BLVD, PISCATAWAY, NJ, 08854], [ADDR, OFF, 211, EXCHANGE PL, JERSEY CITY, NJ, 07302]]           |
+--------+------+---------+--------+----+-----+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

with the below code

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = groupedDataset
                .agg(collect_set(struct(phoneRow.col("type").as("collType"), phoneRow.col("phoneType").as("phoneType"),
                        phoneRow.col("areaCode").as("areaCode"), phoneRow.col("phoneMiddle").as("phoneMiddle"),
                        phoneRow.col("ext").as("ext"), addressRow.col("type").as("collType"),
                        addressRow.col("addrType").as("addrType"), addressRow.col("addr1").as("rowType"),
                        addressRow.col("addr2").as("addr2"), addressRow.col("city").as("city"),
                        addressRow.col("state").as("state"), addressRow.col("zipCode").as("zipCode"))).as("addrPhone"));
```

output is as below, but not the format I am looking for

```
+--------+------+---------+--------+----+-----+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|personId|type  |firstName|lastName|year|month|day|addrPhone                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
+--------+------+---------+--------+----+-----+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|98481   |PERSON|LIN      |JASSOY  |1976|09   |15 |[[PHONE, HOME, 917, 363, 2647, ADDR, OFF, 365, DOWNTOWN NEWYORK, NEWYORK CITY, NY, 10001], [PHONE, HOME, 917, 363, 2647, ADDR, RES, 111, JOURNAL SQ, JERSEY CITY, NJ, 07704], [PHONE, CELL, 908, 398, 3389, ADDR, RES, 111, JOURNAL SQ, JERSEY CITY, NJ, 07704], [PHONE, CELL, 908, 398, 3389, ADDR, OFF, 365, DOWNTOWN NEWYORK, NEWYORK CITY, NY, 10001]]|
|98480   |PERSON|TOM      |GREER   |1982|12   |27 |[[PHONE, HOME, 732, 123, 9876, ADDR, RES, 102, JFK BLVD, PISCATAWAY, NJ, 08854], [PHONE, CELL, 732, 201, 6789, ADDR, RES, 102, JFK BLVD, PISCATAWAY, NJ, 08854], [PHONE, CELL, 732, 201, 6789, ADDR, OFF, 211, EXCHANGE PL, JERSEY CITY, NJ, 07302], [PHONE, HOME, 732, 123, 9876, ADDR, OFF, 211, EXCHANGE PL, JERSEY CITY, NJ, 07302]]                  |
+--------+------+---------+--------+----+-----+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

looking for ideas to fix above issue

***update:***
I was able to get the output as expected but I am not sure how much effective it is and looks like having lot of boiler plate code with lot of joins and dataframes. this is sample data I am playing with to understand spark, but the real data I would be working will have lot of complex transformations and this code doesn't look effective

here is updated code

```
Dataset<Row> groupedPhoneDataSet = groupedDataset.agg(collect_set(struct(phoneRow.col("type").as("phColType"),
                phoneRow.col("phoneType").as("phoneType"), phoneRow.col("areaCode").as("areaCode"),
                phoneRow.col("phoneMiddle").as("phoneMiddle"), phoneRow.col("ext").as("ext"))).as("phoneRec"));

        Dataset<Row> groupedAddrDataSet = groupedDataset
                .agg(collect_set(struct(addressRow.col("type").as("addrColType"),
                        addressRow.col("addrType").as("addrType"), addressRow.col("addr1").as("addr1"),
                        addressRow.col("addr2").as("addr2"), addressRow.col("city").as("city"),
                        addressRow.col("state").as("state"), addressRow.col("zipCode").as("zipCode"))).as("addrRec"));

        Dataset<Row> finalDataSet = groupedAddrDataSet
                .join(groupedPhoneDataSet,
                        groupedAddrDataSet.col("personId").equalTo(groupedPhoneDataSet.col("personId")))
                .select(groupedPhoneDataSet.col("personId"), groupedPhoneDataSet.col("type"),
                        groupedPhoneDataSet.col("firstName"), groupedPhoneDataSet.col("lastName"),
                        groupedPhoneDataSet.col("year"), groupedPhoneDataSet.col("month"),
                        groupedPhoneDataSet.col("day"), col("phoneRec"), col("addrRec"));
```

here is output I got

```
+--------+------+---------+--------+----+-----+---+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|personId|type  |firstName|lastName|year|month|day|phoneRec                                                      |addrRec                                                                                                            |
+--------+------+---------+--------+----+-----+---+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|98481   |PERSON|LIN      |JASSOY  |1976|09   |15 |[[PHONE, CELL, 908, 398, 3389], [PHONE, HOME, 917, 363, 2647]]|[[ADDR, RES, 111, JOURNAL SQ, JERSEY CITY, NJ, 07704], [ADDR, OFF, 365, DOWNTOWN NEWYORK, NEWYORK CITY, NY, 10001]]|
|98480   |PERSON|TOM      |GREER   |1982|12   |27 |[[PHONE, CELL, 732, 201, 6789], [PHONE, HOME, 732, 123, 9876]]|[[ADDR, OFF, 211, EXCHANGE PL, JERSEY CITY, NJ, 07302], [ADDR, RES, 102, JFK BLVD, PISCATAWAY, NJ, 08854]]         |
+--------+------+---------+--------+----+-----+---+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

is there a way I can do it without creating lot of dataframes

Answer (score 0):

if you are okay with creating multiple data frames then,
split each type of records into different data frames and do group by personId,
join all the three data frames on person id.

find the below code that I tried, let me know if it solves your problem.

```
    import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, collect_list, struct}

    object Test {
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val conf = new SparkConf()
        conf.setAppName("Leads Processing Job").setMaster("local[1]")
        val sparkContext = new org.apache.spark.SparkContext(conf)
        val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sparkContext)
        val df = sqlContext.read.option("delimiter","|").format("csv").load("data.csv")
        df.printSchema()
        val df_person = df.where("_c1 = 'PERSON'")
          .select(col("_c0").as("personId"),col("_c1").as("type")
            ,col("_c2").as("firstName"),col("_c3").as("lastName")
            ,col("_c4").as("year"),col("_c5").as("month")
            ,col("_c6").as("day"))

        val df_address = df.where("_c1 = 'ADDR'")
        val df_phone = df.where("_c1 = 'PHONE'")
        val df_addr_f = df_address
          .withColumn("addr",struct(col("_c1"),col("_c2")
            ,col("_c3"),col("_c4"),col("_c5"),col("_c6")))
          .groupBy(col("_c0").as("personId")).agg(collect_list(col("addr")).as("addr"))

        val df_phone_f = df_phone.groupBy(col("_c0").as("personId")).agg(collect_list(struct(col("_c1"),col("_c2")
          ,col("_c3"),col("_c4"),col("_c5"))).as("Phone"))

        val final_df = df_person.join(df_addr_f,"personId").join(df_phone_f,"personId")

        final_df.show(false)
      }
    }
```

It produces below output,

```
            +--------+------+---------+--------+----+-----+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
            |personId|type  |firstName|lastName|year|month|day|addr                                                                                                 |Phone                                                         |
            +--------+------+---------+--------+----+-----+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
            |98480   |PERSON|TOM      |GREER   |1982|12   |27 |[[ADDR, RES, 102, JFK BLVD, PISCATAWAY, NJ], [ADDR, OFF, 211, EXCHANGE PL, JERSEY CITY, NJ]]         |[[PHONE, CELL, 732, 201, 6789], [PHONE, HOME, 732, 123, 9876]]|
            |98481   |PERSON|LIN      |JASSOY  |1976|09   |15 |[[ADDR, RES, 111, JOURNAL SQ, JERSEY CITY, NJ], [ADDR, OFF, 365, DOWNTOWN NEWYORK, NEWYORK CITY, NY]]|[[PHONE, CELL, 908, 398, 3389], [PHONE, HOME, 917, 363, 2647]]|
            +--------+------+---------+--------+----+-----+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can read your data in line-mode, do some data manipulations and then use *collect_list* or *collect_set* to get the desired result:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr, substring_index

# read the files into dataframe with a single column named `value`
df = spark.read.text('/path/to/file/')
```

Split the lines into two columns: `personId` (the 1st field) and an ArrayType column `data` (the rest of the fields):

```
df1 = df.withColumn('personId', substring_index('value', '|', 1)) \
    .selectExpr('personId', 'split(substr(value, length(personId)+2), "[|]") as data')    
#+--------+--------------------+
#|personId|                data|
#+--------+--------------------+
#|   98480|[PERSON, TOM, GRE...|
#|   98480|[PHONE, CELL, 732...|
#|   98480|[PHONE, HOME, 732...|
#|   98480|[ADDR, RES, 102, ...|
#|   98480|[ADDR, OFF, 211, ...|
#|   98481|[PERSON, LIN, JAS...|
#|   98481|[PHONE, CELL, 908...|
#|   98481|[PHONE, HOME, 917...|
#|   98481|[ADDR, RES, 111, ...|
#|   98481|[ADDR, OFF, 365, ...|
#+--------+--------------------+
```

Use groupby + collect_list(or collect_set). **notice that collect_list/collect_set will skip items having NULL values**. Below we use *collect_list* to create 3 ArrayType columns based on the value of `data[0]`:

(1) If data[0] == `PHONE` or `ADDR`, convert `data` into StructType, the result will be array of Structs.

(2) if data[0] == `PERSON`, keep `data` as ArrayType, take the first item (named `d1`) from the resulting array of arrays and then use selectExpr to convert this array `d1` into 6 separate columns.

```
df1.groupby('personId') \
    .agg(
      expr("collect_list(IF(data[0] = 'PERSON', data, NULL))[0] as d1"),
      expr("""
        collect_list(
          IF(data[0] = 'PHONE'
          , (data[0] as phColType,
             data[1] as phoneType,
             data[2] as areaCode,
             data[3] as phoneMiddle,
             data[4] as ext)
          , NULL)
        ) AS Phone"""),
      expr("""
        collect_list(
          IF(data[0] = 'ADDR'
          , (data[0] as addrColType,
             data[1] as addrType,
             data[2] as addr1,
             data[3] as addr2,
             data[4] as city,
             data[5] as state,
             data[6] as zipCode)
          , NULL)
        ) AS Addr""")
    ).selectExpr(
      'personId',
      'd1[0] as type',
      'd1[1] as firstName',
      'd1[2] as lastName',
      'd1[3] as year',
      'd1[4] as month',
      'd1[5] as day',
      'Phone',
      'Addr'
    ).show(truncate=False)
```

The result (Both Phone and Addr are array of structs):

```
+--------+------+---------+--------+----+-----+---+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|personId|type  |firstName|lastName|year|month|day|Phone                                                         |Addr                                                                                                               |
+--------+------+---------+--------+----+-----+---+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|98481   |PERSON|LIN      |JASSOY  |1976|09   |15 |[[PHONE, CELL, 908, 398, 3389], [PHONE, HOME, 917, 363, 2647]]|[[ADDR, RES, 111, JOURNAL SQ, JERSEY CITY, NJ, 07704], [ADDR, OFF, 365, DOWNTOWN NEWYORK, NEWYORK CITY, NY, 10001]]|
|98480   |PERSON|TOM      |GREER   |1982|12   |27 |[[PHONE, CELL, 732, 201, 6789], [PHONE, HOME, 732, 123, 9876]]|[[ADDR, RES, 102, JFK BLVD, PISCATAWAY, NJ, 08854], [ADDR, OFF, 211, EXCHANGE PL, JERSEY CITY, NJ, 07302]]         |
+--------+------+---------+--------+----+-----+---+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```